# Why do i get "thread death" error in JessDE?

Tags: jess

i have a question about jessde. i'm using jess71p2 and eclipse juno with jessde
plugin installed.  i have a jess program (see below) which works at the jess
command prompt. the jess doc says,
"Run and Debug commands for Jess programs
You can run or debug a Jess program using the normal Eclipse "Run..." menu or by
right clicking on Navigator items or in the edit window."

when i try to use the eclipse run command, i get a failure caused by "thread
death". i have setup  a run configuration but still nothing.

any help would be appreciated.

duetto
(deftemplate person
(slot name)
(slot height))
(deffacts people
(person (name Joe) (height 66))
(person (name Jeff) (height 74))
(person (name Janet) (height 62)))
(defrule tallest
(person (name ?name) (height ?h))
(not (person (name ~?name) (height ?ho&:(> ?ho ?h))))
=>
(printout t ?name " is the tallest." crlf))
(reset)
(run)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that’s how the old time-limited downloads “expire”. Nothing you can do about it at the moment, I’m afraid. Working on getting permission to release all of Jess as open source.

Comment: if it's expired, why would it work in jess.Main mode?

Comment: Separate Jess jar file inside the eclipse plugins

Comment: yes, i discovered that also. the jess i have in the main tree is different from the one in the plugin.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Hello efh - good news. Jess as OS would be a great help for propagandizing rule-based programming. And it was always fun to play with ;-) Cheers!